# What's the best way to call another chaincode from inside a chaincode?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I'd like to call another chaincode from inside a chaincode's Invoke() method. What's the recommended way to do this? I guess I can use the standard REST API on /chaincode and reference to it by its ID (returned by the deploy operation), but are there "system" GO APIs to accomplish this, also, can I reference the chaincode by name instead of the ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two samples that might help under fabric/ folder
examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example04
examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example05

Both call chaincode_example02. Only difference between them is that chaincode_example04 hardcodes chaincode_example02's ID and chaincode_exampl05 gets the ID from an argument to Invoke.

Currently, one cannot reference chaincode by name (except in "dev" mode).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @muralisrini, I see that the ChaincodeStub defines a method "InvokeChaincode()". that's what I was looking for. Thanks too for clarifying w.r.t ID vs. name.

Comment: Can you please share the link? Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a set of constraints for calling a chaincode from another chaincode. Please refer to the following link for further details. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/chaincodenamespace.html#cross-chaincode-access>